# Why is the group of gauge transformations $\mathcal{G}$ on the frame bundle isomorphic to $\text{Diff}(M)$?

Tags: fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, diffeomorphism, semi-riemannian-geometry, gauge-theory

Let $LM \to M$ be the frame bundle on pseudo-Riemannian manifold $M$ and suppose that there exists a Lorentzian metric tensor $g \in \Gamma \big(T^0_2(M) \big)$ on $M$. Since the frame bundle is a principal bundle, the group $\mathcal{G}$ of gauge transformations (of the 2nd kind) are bundle automorphisms $LM \to LM$ covering the identity on $M$.

Few decades back, [Trautman (p.306)](http://trautman.fuw.edu.pl/publications/Papers-in-pdf/45_Andrzej_Trautman.pdf) states that any gauge transformation $\phi \in \mathcal{G}$ preserve soldering form $\theta$ and that there exists an isomorphism $\text{Diff}(M) \cong \mathcal{G}$.

I want to prove $\text{Diff}(M) \cong \mathcal{G}$. I understand that one can use a diffeomorphism to induce a gauge transformation in $\mathcal{G}$. But how does one create a diffeomorphism $M \to M$ with a given gauge transformation $LM \to LM$?

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the paper: He really did not mean the gauge group (even though, he wrote one). The group that he meant is the group $Aut(P,\theta)$ of all self-diffeomorphisms of the frame bundle $P\to P$ which preserve the soldering form, send fibers to fibers and restrict to left translations by the structure group on fibers. Each element $f$ of this group descends to a diffeomorphism $\bar{f}: M\to M$ of the base and he observes that the map  $f\mapsto \bar{f}$ is a group isomorphism, $Aut(P,\theta)\to Diff(M)$.

As for the group ${\mathcal G}(P)$ of gauge transformations of a principal fiber bundle (with the structure group $G$ of positive dimension) over a smooth manifold $M$, one can show that it is **never** isomorphic to the group $Diff(M)$. The key reason is that the identity component of $Diff(M)$ is simple as an abstract group. On the other hand, ${\mathcal G}(P)$ admits an epimorphism to the structure group $G$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Moishe! I would like to question you some more, if you are okay with that, on the interpretation of this group $\text{Aut}(P, \theta)$. 

If I understand correctly, the soldering form on principal bundle $P \to M$ is the map
$$ \theta: dx^i \otimes \dot{\partial}_i  \in \Gamma( T^*M \otimes VP ),$$
where $VP$ is the vertical tangent bundle. What does it mean for a self-diffeomorphism $P \to P$ to be preserving the soldering form $\theta$? Is this preservation related to the group $\mathcal{G}(P)$ of gauge transformations?